# retained two attorneys

Tags: grammar

Does "retained two attorneys" mean "kept two attorneys in place"? If so, does it imply (the two attorneys) "in order to monitor"? Or "in order to help"?

Pierce Bainbridge Beck Price & Hecht and Davidoff Hutcher & Citron
On November 9, 2019, during the Ukraine scandal, Giuliani **retained two attorneys** with the Los Angeles law firm Pierce Bainbridge Beck Price & Hecht which has also represented George Papadopoulos and Tulsi Gabbard and one attorney with the New York law firm Davidoff Hutcher & Citron who previously represented Michael Cohen.

Source: Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudy_Giuliani#Pierce_Bainbridge_Beck_Price_&_Hecht_and_Davidoff_Hutcher_&_Citron

Comment: It's [the specialised legal sense:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retain)  *to get the services of a lawyer by paying them before you need them*. It's more or less the same as saying ***he hired a couple of lawyers***. Ignore the detail about "before he needs them" - the exact terms of the contract is a private matter between Giuliana and the lawyers he's struck some kind of deal with, which we don't know the details of.

Comment: What FF says is supported by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/retain) with **4.1** Secure the services of (a barrister) with a preliminary payment. There is also the noun [**retainer**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/retainer): **2** A fee paid in advance to someone, especially a barrister, in order to secure their services for use when required.

Comment: Thank you.     Now it is clear. What added to the confusion was the use of "with" - "Giuliani retained two attorneys with the Los Angeles law firm": Were two attoneys the lawyers from the law firm? Could it be expressed as "Giuliani retained two attorneys from the Los Angeles law firm"?